# Invalid encoded Base64 image data

Tags: ios, swift, base64

I try to encode an image in Base64 and I get a string which looks correct, but when I try to load the image in PHP, I get a wrong file from iOS which is illisible. (My Android version of the app puts valid base64 files that can be read)

here's my code :

```
if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)

        var encodedImageData = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as NSString
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, encodedImageData.length)
        encodedImageData = encodedImageData.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "%2B", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: range)
        encodedImageData = encodedImageData.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("/", withString: "%2F", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: range)
        let utilisateurId = PlistManager.sharedInstance.getValueForKey("id")
```

I tried many configurations but I can't get one valid.

On the Android size it's :

```
bitmapLoaded.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
                 byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                 String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: can you post how you are convert you image to base65 in app side ?

Comment: On my android app ?

Comment: yes on android side

Comment: I did it just now

Comment: i have added my answer. You might have problem with bitmap

Comment: Uh, why the percent replacing? I really have to wonder why encoding image data to Base64 is even necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting image from camera.

```
Bitmap bmp1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp1, 300, 300, true);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
byte[] imageByte = baos.toByteArray();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(imageByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.d("tag", "base64 : " + encoded);
```

from gallery,

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
    Bitmap newbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 600, 600, true);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    newbmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
    byte[] imageByte = baos.toByteArray();
    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(imageByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**Edited Answer**

**how we can get base64 in IOS**

## Swift 3 (iOS 10+)

```
let plainString = "foo"
```

#### Encoding

```
let plainData = plainString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedString()
print(base64String!) // Zm9v
```

#### Decoding

```
if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String!),
   let decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding:  String.Encoding.utf8) {
  print(decodedString) // foo
}
```

---

## Swift < 3

```
let plainString = "foo"
```

#### Encoding

```
let plainData = plainString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
print(base64String!) // Zm9v
```

#### Decoding

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String!, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(decodedString) // foo
```

---

## Objective-C

```
NSString *plainString = @"foo";
```

#### Encoding

```
NSData *plainData = [plainString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64String); // Zm9v
```

#### Decoding

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", decodedString); // foo
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: You didn't understand, it works from Android, but not from iOS !

Comment: which one ios you are trying ?

Comment: iOS 9.3 why is this important ?

Comment: yes it depends, i have updated my answer please check